# Page doesn't destroy/unload itself after OnNavigatedFrom

Tags: c#, wpf, memory, navigation, uwp

I am using a frame to show my current page. The user can switch between two pages.

I navigate to the pages via:

```
frame.Navigate(typeof(FirstPage));
```

and

```
frame.Navigate(typeof(SecondPage));
```

I thought that every time I switch between the pages the old page will be destoyed/unload all it's content.

But looking on the memory usage, it doesn't look like it:

[image: Image of memory usage]

(every time I navigate to the `SecondPage` I run the garbage collector so you can see when a navigation occured)

Do I have to change the `frame.Navigation()` method or do I have to add something to the `OnNavigationFrom()` method?

Comment: What is the NavigationCacheMode in the SecondPage?  Best advice is to stop worrying about this, you don't have a memory leak.  And do stop to "run the garbage collector".

Comment: Thanks :)
The caching is disabled and I only run the garbage collector so it's easier to see when a navigation occurred. So it was only temporary to illustrate the "problem"

Comment: To make this a productive question, you'll have to create a [MCVE]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don't want the app to cosume much memory after navigation, just set the [`NavigationCacheMode`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.xaml.navigation.navigationcachemode) [property](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.xaml.controls.page.navigationcachemode) on your pages to `NavigationCacheMode.Required`.

Your app will not be creating new instances of the pages everytime you navigate to them.

Comment: okay but how to remove an already cached page ?