# Win 10 UWP App consuming RAM on navigation between pages

Tags: performance, xaml, uwp, windows-10

I am doing performance test of my UWP application and I've noticed that the app starts consuming 1 or more than 1 mb of RAM after each page load to the point that it bloats from 50 mb to 500 mb!

There is one background thread running in the application and even after closing the thread I've noticed same behavior. Shouldn't the xaml load from the cache rather than a new object being dispatched after each page load?

Any suggestions?

Comment: It's a File New Project or there are some extra specific things?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Page doesn't destroy/unload itself after OnNavigatedFrom](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41531190/page-doesnt-destroy-unload-itself-after-onnavigatedfrom)

Comment: @TóthTibor Its a developed application, it has some 5 or 6 pages.

Comment: @Anss Take a look at [my answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/41532566/6843321) for the [similar question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41531190/page-doesnt-destroy-unload-itself-after-onnavigatedfrom). It should help you approach what you want.

Comment: @MarianDolinský That solved the problem, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Set [NavigationCacheMode](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/Windows.UI.Xaml.Navigation.NavigationCacheMode) property of your pages to "Enabled" or "Required" and this should be fix.